# Javascript merge array combined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
const sizes = ['large', 'medium']
const colors = ['blue', 'red', 'orange']
```

I need to create a final array that combines the array's with all possible values like so:

```
const final = ['blue large', 'red large', 'orange large', 'blue medium', 'red medium', 'orange medium']
```

Both `sizes` and `colors` can be empty.

I prefer to do this with `lodash` and I've tried forEach looping like so:

```
sizes.forEach((size) => {
  colors.forEach((color) => {
    actualVariants.push(`${size} ${color}`)
  })
})

colors.forEach((size) => {
  sizes.forEach((color) => {
    actualVariants.push(`${color} ${size}`)
  })
})
```

Now that did work, however: it contains duplicates and I want to make sure I do it in the most efficient way possible.

This also doesn't work when the arrays are empty.

Comment: Share the `forEach` loop you've tried and explain what's not working as intended.

Comment: @user3297291Done, sorry for that.

Comment: No need for lodash... And your code basically works... And there are no duplicates??

Comment: it contains duplicate because you have 4 forEach loop, only 2 are necessaries. actualVariants.push(`${size} ${color}`) doesn't do what you want since you want the color at the beggining.

Comment: @epitouille depends if "orange medium" and "medium orange" are duplicates...

Comment: Yes, and that's what I want to prevent.

Comment: @Jonasw I agree but I based my comment on the `final` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove you first block :

Example here: https://jsbin.com/qovojacuci/edit?js,console

```js
const sizes = ['large', 'medium']
const colors = ['blue', 'red', 'orange']

let actualVariants = []

colors.forEach((size) => {
  sizes.forEach((color) => {
    actualVariants.push(`${color} ${size}`)
  });
});

console.log(actualVariants);
```

If you want your array sorted like you `final` constant, change the loop order:

```js
const sizes = ['large', 'medium']
const colors = ['blue', 'red', 'orange']

let actualVariants = []

sizes.forEach((size) => {
  colors.forEach((color) => {
    actualVariants.push(`${color} ${size}`)
  });
});

console.log(actualVariants);
```

Comment: This will not work, because: what is the colors are empty? I still want the final result to contain: blue red and orange. I will make my question more clear.

Comment: @randomKek **what is the colors are empty? I still want the final result to contain: blue red and orange.**: When the array colors is empty how can you have blue, red and orange in your final result??

Answer (score 0):

And a solution via for loop:

```js
const sizes = ['large', 'medium'];
const colors = ['blue', 'red', 'orange'];

var final=new Array();

for(var i=0;i<sizes.length;i++){
  for(var z=0;z<colors.length;z++){
    final.push(colors[z]+' '+sizes[i]);
  }
}
console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd define a general purpose `combine` method that can combine two arrays in to one.

The method will always loop `arr1.length * arr2.length` times to be able to produce all valid results. So, for `['a', 'b', 'c']` and `[1, 2]` you'll get `3 x 2 = 6` combine calls and an array of length `6`.

A benefit of writing it as a function that takes two arrays and returns one, and supports empty arrays, is that you can use it inside `reduce` to combine *any number of arrays*!

```js
// `combiner` is a function that combines an element from `xs`
// and one from `ys` in to one value
const combine = combiner => (xs, ys) => {
  if (!xs || !xs.length) return ys;
  if (!ys || !ys.length) return xs;
  
  // Note, this can still be done using two forEach loops
  // in some cases, `concat` might be too slow...
  return xs.reduce(
    (acc, x) => acc.concat(ys.map(combiner(x))),
    []
  );
}
  
// Example use:

// Make different combiners:
const combineWithSpace = combine(x => y => `${x} ${y}`);
const combineWithDot = combine(x => y => `${x}.${y}`);

const prefix = ["a", "b", "c"];
const suffix = [1, 2];

// Now  you can do:
log("Prefix Suffix:", combineWithSpace(prefix, suffix));

// Support for empty arrays:
log("One empty array:", combineWithSpace(prefix, []));

// But you can also use it as a reducer:
log("Custom:", 
  [prefix, suffix, ["i", "ii", "iii"]].reduce(combineWithDot)
);


function log(label, arr) { console.log(label, JSON.stringify(arr)) };
```